# How do I count number of times second column appears in text file

Tags: count, text-files

I have a text file with 2 columns and I need to know how I can count how many time the second column appears in my file, for example:

```
i3019225    ^b3340515
i3019226    ^b3340515
i3019227    ^b3340515
i3019238    ^b3340524
i3019239    ^b3340524
i3019969    ^b3341058
i3020650    ^b3341525
i3020650    ^b3341525
i3020651    ^b3341525
i3020651    ^b3341525
i3020652    ^b3341525
i3020652    ^b3341525
i3020653    ^b3341525
i3020653    ^b3341525
i3020654    ^b3341525
i3020654    ^b3341525
i3020655    ^b3341525
i3020655    ^b3341525
i3020656    ^b3341525
i3020656    ^b3341525
i3020657    ^b3341525
i3020657    ^b3341525
```

Comment: You need to be much more specific. For instance, what language, system and hardware are you asking about? [SO] is not a code writing service either, so you should show us what you have tried and how it failed and then we can help you solve the problem with that,

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really formulated too well, but, in copying and pasting the your exact example string above into a file named "test", I ran:

`sed -e 's/ i/\'$'\n/g' test | sed 's/^i//g' | sed -e 's/[0-9]* ^//g' | sort | uniq -c`

which produced this output:

`3 b3340515
   2 b3340524
   1 b3341058
  16 b3341525`

which I am pretty sure would answer your question.

Disclaimer: this was used on a Mac OSX Bash, and also the command is specific to your provided example. The key here is that one possible solution is to use `sed` to identify the "column" you want, so it is the only data point on each line in the file, and then perform a `uniq -c` on that output to see how many times each unique datapoint occurs.

Comment: i have 2 columns,

Comment: i1234567    b1234567        <<<<   how many times does column 2 appear in my list of 2k lines with same format first column has i[0-9] and second column has b[0-9]